# org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503 (google scholar ban?)

Tags: connection, web-crawler, jsoup, http-status-code-503, google-crawlers

I am working on crawler and I have to extract data from 200-300 links on Google Scholar. I have working parser which is getting data from pages (on every pages are 1-10 people profiles as result of my query. I'm extracting proper links, go to another page and do it again). During run of my program I spotted above error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=https://scholar.google.pl/citations%3Fmauthors%3DAGH%2BUniversity%2Bof%2BScience%2Band%2BTechnology%26hl%3Dpl%26view_op%3Dsearch_authors&q=CGMSBFMKrI0YiJHfqgUiGQDxp4NLfGBv6zgPSjfyQ9LBi5F-K1EbGwQ
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
```

I know it is linked with simple google protection against robots. How I can improve my connection

```
    Connection connection = 
             Jsoup.connect(url)
              .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
              .timeout(10000)
              .followRedirects(true);
```

to not have temporary ban? I know there is a way to check response, like this:

```
Connection.Response response = 
           Jsoup.connect(url)
           .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
           .timeout(10000)
           .execute();

int statusCode = response.statusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) { ... }
else if (statusCode == 503) { do recconect magic}
```

But what should I do, when I got 503 error? Have I to use proxy? Random wait time beetween connections? I hope there is better idea than saving my results in file, do manual hard-restart of router and try with new IP :P

Comment: It's quite clear: Google doesn't want you to scrape their site for data. Only workaround would be to use a proxy, but that won't really work very well for long. There are unofficial api's such as [this pyton one](https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py), but you won't really have better results. Check [this](http://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Google-have-an-official-API-for-Google-Scholar) for the reasons that Google does not want you to scrape data, [cont..]

Comment: and check [this](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/About/Help.htm) for the Microsoft Achademic Search Api, which may offer what you want. (scroll down).

Comment: What sort of delay are you placing between each scrape? If the answer is "none at all" then you deserve the ban - on a good server/connection that could overload a target with a denial of service (in practice it won't with Google, but that would be to miss the point). Can you place a few seconds delay between each HTTP op? That might help - I use five seconds.

Comment: @Izzy hi bro , do u mind to share the code to resolve the soft ban by Google. As i m doing the similar stuff to extract data from google news

Answer (score 1):

You have already provided your own answers...

> Have I to use proxy?

Of course. You should already have setup a bunch of proxies for your wrawling activity.

> Random wait time beetween connections?

Yes. Use some random wait between 3000 and 5000 ms.

Alternatively, you could use an online captcha service resolving if you hit the URL `https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect...`. Don't hit it too often or you'll get banned.

Happy coding :)