# Temporary ban of google search by Google (HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503 )

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, google-search, google-search-api

For my code ,it aims to retrieve every google search results in that specific date range . It works once .And later I re-run again .It fails .And I have received the error before .

> > Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://www.google.com/search%253Fq%253Dstackoverflow%2526tbm%253Dnws%2526tbs%253Dcdr%2525253A1%2525252Ccd_min%2525253A5%2525252F30%2525252F2016%2525252Ccd_max%2525253A6%2525252F30%2525252F2016%2526start%253D0&q=EgTKLTckGKH5hsQFIhkA8aeDS-3IYZmr41q-m4rIMh7Uw7vC3wdLMgNyY24 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:679) at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676) at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628) at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260) at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249) at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:36)

By referencing [org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503 (google scholar ban?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281650/org-jsoup-httpstatusexception-http-error-fetching-url-status-503-google-schol) & [Using Jsoup to access HTML but receives error code 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700926/using-jsoup-to-access-html-but-receives-error-code-503)

I guess the crawling is too fast so it causes the Google temporary ban.
Hence ,I set this .

`.ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();`

However ,it is still not working .

Full code:`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

        String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

        String search = "stackoverflow daterange:2016-01-01..2016-12-31 ";

   //+"&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016"
      //  daterange:2457389-2457735

        String charset = "UTF-8";

        String news="&tbm=nws";

          String string = google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news;

       // String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)"; // Change this to your company's name and bot homepage!
     String userAgent ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";
        int pages =0;


for(int j=0;j<50;j++){
    //   Document document = Jsoup.connect(string+"&start="+(j+0)*10).userAgent(userAgent).get(); <<-- original method 
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(string+"&start="+(j+0)*10).userAgent(userAgent). ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();  //<<-- modified method
    Elements links = document.select( ".r>a");

     int numberOfResultpages = 1; 

  System.out.println("\n"); System.out.println(j);
   for(int i=0;i<numberOfResultpages ;i++) {

     for (Element link : links) {
            String title = link.text();
            String url = link.absUrl("href"); // Google returns URLs in format "http://www.google.com/url?q=<url>&sa=U&ei=<someKey>".
            url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

            if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
                continue; // Ads/news/etc.
            }

            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        }
    }

}
  }`
```

Comment: Putting timeout does not mean that you have time between the requests, It's the time after which request expires. You need to manually sleep the thread or use ScheduledTask with futures.

Comment: @Ramandeep Nanda how to sleep the thread?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html. I'd say use executors https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html.

Comment: @Ramandeep Nanda Then ,how to unlock the temporary google search ban if it is?

Comment: Change your ip? Ask Google. Former is better.